# call iSeries AS400 program with cwbx in console application in C#

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange

I am trying to use **cwbx** library (IBM i Access for Windows ActiveX automation objects) from a console application (or from a Windows Service application), but it seems to be very slow.

I have a program which requires a complex input with:

- **3** single structures (`cwbx.Structure`)
- **5** structure arrays. The **5** arrays contains, respectively **30, 300, 10, 20** and **10** elements with different fields (`cwbx.StructureField`).

The total number of structure objects to pass is **373** plus the **5** fake structures that identifies the 5 arrays.

If I call this program from a WPF application, it runs smoothly in `0.4230891` seconds.
If I run the same program in a console application, in runs much more slowly in `2.5116918` seconds.

I then added some stopwatches to calculate the timings and it turned out that `program.Call(parameters)` takes the same amount of time.

The difference lies in the construction and assignment of the input parameters.

Does cwbx require a Window Handle or something like that to explain the slow running in console application?

Has anyone noticed this problem and found a workaround for this slowdown?

**Edit:** I am now adding some code to clarify:

### CWBX Example

```
var system = new AS400System();
system.Define("AS400");
system.UserID = "USER";
system.Password = "PASSWORD";
system.IPAddress = "192.168.1.55";
system.PromptMode = cwbcoPromptModeEnum.cwbcoPromptNever;
system.Signon();
system.Connect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd);
try
{
    // Check the connection
    if (system.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd) == 1)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.LibraryName = "*LIBL";
        program.ProgramName = "BW6IF";
        program.system = system;
        // Create a collection of parameters associated with the program
        var parameters = new ProgramParameters();

        //[... parameters creation ...]

        // Finally call the program
        try
        {
            program.Call(parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (system.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Error error in system.Errors)
                {
                    // log somewhere: error.Text
                }
            }
            if (program.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Error error in program.Errors)
                {
                    // log somewhere: error.Text
                }
            }
            // log somewhere: ex.Message
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    system.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAll);
}
```

Comment: Slow time usually means a different driver is being used by the two apps.  See list of drivers for AS400 at top of following : https://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400/

Comment: @jdweng: I am not using an implementation of IDbConnection for the task, I am using the CWBX ActiveX library from IBM Client Access, and I am referencing the same dll from both WPF and Console applications

Comment: IBM Client Access is quite old, and does not really support Windows 8+ very well. Yes it is that old. The newest client is IBM i Access Client Solutions. It should work better with newer versions of windows as it is the currently supported client.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: I think I mispelled the name of the library, I have the IBM i Access for Windows 7.1.. is there something newer?

Comment: If one app is slower than the other you must be using a different connection string.

Comment: @Formentz Yes, IBM i Access for Windows was the previous client. Here is the current client: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions

Comment: BTW, on the same website, there is an announcement that IBM i Access for Windows 7.1 was withdrawn in 2019.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I tried to install the latest ibm ACS, but nothing changed, the slowdown is still here. It seems, anyway, that the cwbx.dll hasn't changed